# Помогите перевести на русский цитату про penny

Tags: перевод

**Ever notice how it's a penny for your thoughts, yet you put in your two-cents? Someone is making a penny on the deal.**

мой перевод

Когда-либо замечали что значит для вас один цент,  а когда вы еще добавили два? Кто-то делает цент на сделке.

Comment: This is a word play on two English idioms: "a penny for your thoughts" and "my two cents". The first one does not have a Russian equivalent, the second does: *мои пять копеек*. This site is not a translation service, so you'll have to connect the two in Russian yourself.